# Nginx With SSL and Frontend + Backend same server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have a server (VPS Amazon) with Ubuntu. In this server is running my backend node and my frontend React.
My ReactApp is running over nginx and my backend over pm2.

In my react app I defined REACT_APP_BASE_URL: http://[my_ip_server]:4000.
So everything was working OK but after I configured SSL in nginx, I can access my frontend login page but when I send the request, I catch the following errors:

a) If I set https in my REACT_APP_BASE_URL (https://[my_ip_server]:4000), I get this error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
b) If I let with http, I get Mixed Content error

Someone know How I do this work?

Thanks a lot!

My nginx.conf. At moment I'm using just port 80 until I solve my problem.

```
server {

        #listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.br/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com.br/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        #if ($host = surveys.alcancenet.com.br) {
        #  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        #} # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name mysite.com.br;
        #return 404; # managed by Certbot

        root /var/www/html;
        
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri /index.html;


        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is a difference between running the applications (which is what i assume you are using PS2 for), and exposing them through an nginx proxy.

It would be most helpful to show us your nginx config file, and also tell us which port your backend runs on (assuming the frontend runs on port 4000).

Edit;
Thanks for the config and backend port.

I don't think you need to set the create react app base url to https, just set the port and run it on the VPS using PS2.

I can't see how you have any proxy at all pointing to 4000 in your config - do you not expose the backend?

The only exposed part is static html files. The relevant code is;

```
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
}
```

If you want to call the backend using https, or generate your site using some tool with a process which entails HTTPS calls, you need to do so correctly in the frontend. IE something doesn't add up here.

The usual approach is;
Expose the backend and the frontend on port 443 SSL only, using different sub-domains (eg. api.mydomain.com), and then use the proxy in nginx to redirect 443 traffic for each domain to the corresponding local ports (4000, and the frontend port or static files directory more likely).

Instead of:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
}
```

Use something like:

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
}
```

Comment: Tks Markido. I put my nginx.conf

Comment: My backend runs on port 4000

Comment: Hi Markido. Sorry, but I did not understand about the approach that you talk here.
I don't have experience with applications deploy, etc. 
I agree with you that running application node with pm2 and serve react app with nginx are distinct things, but really don't know how to make this the correct way.

I just followed a video tutorial and if was not this question about SSL, would be every OK.

Could you pass me what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Hi again. Please see the updated answer - you might want to find another turtorial, as i think you are off track a bit.

Comment: Hi Markido. I could finally to solve my problem. I used basically what you said me. I did just an update in my backend setting a default route like "/api" and in my nginx config put in my location "/api" and worked. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Hi - i am glad to hear that! if you liked my "answer", don't forget to mark it as correct and upvote. Good luck on your project

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Markido. I managed to solve that.

I added in my backend the default route "/api" and after that I put in my nginx config the following

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
}
```

Tks!!!